# How can I run Cucumber with mother language?

Tags: java, cucumber

How can I run Cucumber-JVM with my mother tongue.

My feature looks like this:

> Funkcja: Chcę sprawdzić czy silnik JavaWww uwzględnia wszystkie
>   możliwości logowania
>
> > Scenariusz: Zaloguj użytkownika który zna swój login i hasło
> >
> > ```
> >  Zakładając wprowadzenie nazwy uzytkownika Martin i hasła admin1
> >
> >  Oraz że w bazie istnieje użytkownik o loginie Martin i haśle admin1
> >
> >  Jeżeli wyslę żądanie zalogowania
> >
> >  Wtedy wtedy Martin będzie zalogowany
> > ```

I had import all annotations:

> import cucumber.api.java.pl.Jeżeli;
>
> import cucumber.api.java.pl.Oraz;
>
> import cucumber.api.java.pl.Wtedy;
>
> import cucumber.api.java.pl.Zakładając;

My pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And still I get Parse Error:

> gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 1: '...'. See
>   https://github.com/cucumber-attic/gherkin2/wiki/LexingError for more
>   information.  at gherkin.lexer.En.scan(En.java:872)   at
>   gherkin.lexer.I18nLexer.scan(I18nLexer.java:30)   at
>   gherkin.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:58)   at
>   cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:113)    at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:40)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:117)
>     at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:62)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pom.xml I should to add this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And in classes I should use this:

```
    import cucumber.api.java.pl.Jeśli;
    import cucumber.api.java.pl.Wtedy;
    import cucumber.api.java.pl.Zakładając;
```

Also in feature start should be:

```
    # language: pl
```